# How to save bitmap in database?

Tags: android

I want to know how to save a bitmap in database. I created table in db as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,image BLOB)");         
}
```

My problem is I am not able to insert the image. Please tell me in which format I need to insert the image.

Comment: I wonder why would you want to save it to the database. you can save the image somewhere and store its path in the database.

Answer (score 16):

If you have Bitmap image then you can do following.

```
Bitmap photo = <Your image>
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

Then you can save data in table using following way.

```
db = YourDBHelper.getInstance(ctx).getWritableDatabase();    
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
values.put("image", bArray);            
db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null, values);
```

Comment: +1 Other than not showing the `create table` code, this should be Accepted.

Comment: It is not recommended to store image in database but in file system with path saved in db table.

Comment: Should we store images to user phone memory or SD card? Is storing byte array in sqlite is inefficient?

Answer (score 10):

if you want to do that you need to use a blob. but why do you have to do this.. i wouldn't store images into a database. its better to store the image on the sdcard and then store its path into the database. often databases are installed on the phone memory and that will just fill the phone memory up...

Answer (score 0):

Write it to binary and store as a BLOB... You are on the right track. You can also do it with objects.

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/jdbc/LOBS/BLOBFileExample.java

Dont forget Google code too:

http://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+write+to+binary+and+store+in+BLOB#hl=de&safe=off&sa=X&ei=9y_3TbzLBcOZOobyqagK&ved=0CBgQBSgA&q=google+code+java+write+to+binary+and+stored+in+BLOB&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=562730531e5070d5&biw=1440&bih=787

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
InputStream is = mycon.getAssets().open("data/Images/img1");
                if (is.available() == -1) {
                    Log.v(null, "Images not read to Input stream");
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 128);
                    ByteArrayBuffer barb = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);
                    // read the bytes one by one and append it into the
                    // ByteArrayBuffer barb
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        barb.append((byte) current);
                    }
                    values.put("imageData", barb.toByteArray());
```