# how to save a image in database

Tags: android, database, image, camera, imageview

I follow this [Instruction](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/) and it works.

Problem:

- Every time I exit my application I need to capture again another image but the image that was been capture is save in the android gallery

Question:

- How can I save the image in database so when I open my application the image will be their.

Comment: If you have a bitmap (or a way of converting the image to a bitmap)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341776/how-to-save-bitmap-in-database

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some comments suggest, image format doesn't matter. You can either save it as BLOB (`byte[]`) or text (converting it to Base64).

Anyway it's not a good idea to store images in a DB, prefer a file, [as argued over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347461/saving-images-files-or-blobs).

Answer (score 0):

i will advice you get the path at which the image is located at in the android device and load up on your application start. the case of saving it in a database is not cool.  that is like consuming  the user's memory space on the database side and also the device storage which is not cool.